# I'm having trouble reading a properties file using FileInputStream

Tags: java, file-io, classpath

I'm working on a web application, and I have created a properties file in package com.xx.yy. I need to read this file from a class in author package com.aa.bb.

I have the folowing code:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("com/xx/yy/myfile.properties");
    internationalizationFile = new Properties();
    internationalizationFile.load(fileInputStream);
    fileInputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but it doesn't work!!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to load the resource through the class loader? like:

```
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("com/xx/yy/myfile.properties");
```

Answer (score 2):

1) I would print out the absolute path to make sure the file / resource is in the correct location.

[getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2308188/974465)

2) I would use getResourceAsStream, same reference.